# Three js Explode Modifier with Material

Tags: three.js, webgl

Trying to mimic the behaviour of this site.
http://experience.mausoleodiaugusto.it/it/chapter-02

I can successfully load in a dae model with a texture and have this displayed in the 3JS scene. I have also played around a bit with the tesselate and explode modifiers with reasonable success however the method I am using takes the dae geometry, creates faces from this, which are assigned a colour and turned into new mesh and added to the scene alongside my original dae model. So I end up with two objects - my original dae model with texture and the new exploded mesh with coloured faces

How would I map the texture from the dae file to each individual face in the new mesh so that when it explodes it looks accurate as per the example - or am I going about this the wrong way? Perhaps each face needs its inidvidual texture already mapped in the dae file?

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: when you copy the mesh faces dont just copy position and normal but also copy the uv coords. Assign the texture to the copied object and explode it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - will give that a shot.